# xCode Applescript: disable a UI button

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript-objc

i am building a simple(ish) applescript app using xCode and not the applescript app.

I have set up several buttons via the GUI and have linked them to the retrospective code via the drag and drop method in xcode

```
    on ThisIsMyButton_()

      ....

   end ThisIsMyButton_
```

But i am having trouble disabling them via code.

I have tried the following but get error

```
   set enabled of button "ThisIsMyButton_" to false
```

But as the name of the button is not set on the GUI i think its finding it hard to locate the button in question.

Any ideas much appreciated,

Using xCode 6.0.1 on an iMac

Comment: Did you create an outlet pointing to the button? You need it to talk back from your script to the UI.

Comment: To create an outlet, add a line like `property myButton : missing value` to your AppDelegate.applescript, save it. After that switch to the interface builder view and ctrl-drag from the App Delegate object to your button and connect it to the outlet.

Comment: Detailed instructions for buttons in ASOC can be found at http://asobjcresources.weebly.com/connecting-buttons-to-applescript.html